# Node.js Installation - CentOS 6.9

Tags: node.js, installation, centos, centos6

I'm wondering if anyone else has experience installing node.js and NPM on a `centOS` 6.9 or other `centOS` version installation. I'd really like to install it to begin using `NPM` specifically, but the server I'm using is used for production already.

My primary concern before installing is that I can't risk having any downtime on my current server or website, which is currently built on CMS Made Simple / `PHP / MySQL`.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with a VM or other non-production environment so you can try out the process first.  Not sure why you'd start experimenting on a production box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'd rather install Node.js in production environment using Node Version Manager (NVM). In this link you can find a good help:

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-for-node-js-on-centos-7/

After installing NVM, running `nvm install 8` on the terminal, installs Node.js version 8 stable on your server.